# CSS animation not working at all

Tags: css

I don't know where is the problem.

```css
.media-p .see-more .box  {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(2000px);
    transform: translateY(2000px);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="see-more">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="box midia">
      <h3>Midia</h3>

      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" class="img-responsive img-circle">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the same code format in other animation, and is working.
I'm using the animate.css.

The link for the external css is working good, before someone ask :B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a duration to your animation, like so:

```
-webkit-animation: 1s bounceInUp;
```

---

```css
.see-more .box  { -webkit-animation: 1s bounceInUp; }

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% { -webkit-transform: translateY(10px); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

```html
<div class="see-more">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="box midia">
            <h3>Midia</h3>

            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" class="img-responsive img-circle"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```